# Make submit button expand left when label text grows

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to create something that looks like an input group from Bootstrap, with the attached button on the right.

I originally was using their control, except I need to have the button grow to the **LEFT** instead of the normal to the right as the button label gets larger.

For example, if the button said "go" after click it needs to say "processing your data" and then in a few seconds back to "go" and normal width.

I tried fixed positioning and other tricks, but the button still grew to the right OR the button and the input field came apart when the window was resized.

So I'm trying Flexbox:

```
.input-group-msgbox {
    display: flex;
    input {
      // Shrink and grow as needed, but never shrink so
      // small that we can't read the placeholder
      flex: 1 0 8em;
    }
    .btn {
      // Never shrink or grow
      flex: 0 0 auto;
    }
}
```

please see this pen: http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/wKdVMP

It does everything but the text "grow-left".  Ideas?

Comment: I don't get why the standard bootstrap setup doesn't work for you. If I change the text in the button, the button grows to the left and the input gets smaller. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvwgpY

Comment: @Sebsemillia - Exactly, same thing over here [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xhe0u3c3/). This is the default behavior of `.input-group`. @Steve -  You should not need any special CSS to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

So here are two general options (non-Bootstrap):

#### Option #1

Change the [**`direction`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) of the `div` container from left-to-right to right-to-left:

```
.input-group-msgbox { direction: rtl; }
```

Then reverse the order of the `<input>` and `<button>` in the source:

```
<div class="input-group-msgbox">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ... > ... </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ...>
</div>
```

Then apply left-to-right `direction` to `<input>` and `<button>`:

```
input { direction: ltr; }
.btn { direction: ltr; }
```

The submit button now grows to the left when the label text expands.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MamNqM)

#### Option #2

[LADDA](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/) scripting solution.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, as much as the question.